# AWS DMS is failing on some collections

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to understand why 3 of my collections is failing during the migration.
I got the error `Execute bulk failed with errors: ‘invalid document for insert: empty key'` but didn't managed to understand and solve this issue.

I'm using DocumentDB both source DB and target.

Does someone know this error?

Comment: Hi Nir, do any of your collections have documents where one of the fields is empty? For example - 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf9b5b34b63125fa4f03f8"), "name" : "Mary", "" : "SEA" }

In this document, the field 'name' has a value of 'Mary', but the second field is empty.

Comment: Thank meet-bhagdev!
But do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Find the documents using db..find({"": { $exists: true}}). Perform an update() using $unset to remove the empty-named field entirely.